# Auto-boxing followed by Widening in Java

Tags: java, autoboxing

Following program prints `Object` as output, and when I remove the overloaded method contains `Object` as parameters, following compile time error is there:

> The method m1(Long) in the type LangPackage is not applicable for the
>   arguments (int)

```
 public class A {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      int x = 0;
       m1(x);

    }
    static void m1(Long l) {
            System.out.println("long");

        }

        static void m1(Object l) {
            System.out.println("Object");

        }
}
```

My query is why `auto-boxing` followed by widening is allowed for `Objects` not for `Long` type

Comment: Implicit widening then autoboxing simply isn't defined to happen in the language spec. You are invoking the `Object` overload because it autoboxes to `Integer`.

Answer (score 6):

`auto-boxing` boxes an `int` to an `Integer`.

An `Integer` is an `Object`, but it's not a `Long`. Therefore `static void m1(Long l)` cannot be chosen.

If you would call the method with a `long` parameter (i.e. if `x` would be a `long`), it would be auto-boxed to `Long`, and `static void m1(Long l)` would be preferred over `static void m1(Object l)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you call m1 with a long, the output is `long`:

```
m1(1L);
```

If you call with an integer - `m1(1)` - Java will choose the method with the Object parameter.

If you change input parameter from `Long` to `long`, the output is `long` for `m1(1)`:

```
static void m1(long l) {
```

This works because `int` and `long` (not `Integer` and `Long`) are primitive types and Java converts from `int` to `long` in a case like this.

Integer does not extend Long, or vice versa. But both extend Number, so if you change to:

```
static void m1(Number n) {
```

That method will be called for `m1(1)`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.